# Select listview item, place value in form field, and close list view - Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, google-places-api, google-places

I have a listview thats connected to the google places api and it updates as the user inputs at address. When the user clicks the address I want to the address to be placed in the text field and the listview to close.

selectedItem in the code below is the item the user selected. I'm trying to update the textformfield with the selectedItem. Any ideas?

TextFormFiled and ListView.builder:

```
    TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
          labelText: 'Address or Perferred City'),
    ),
    ListView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _placeList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Text(_placeList[index]["description"]),
              onTap: () {
                selectedItem = _placeList[index]["description"];
                print(selectedItem);
              });
        }),
```

Image of listview being built in app:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` condition here. Initially `selectedItem` is `null`, so `ListView` is visible, once an item is chosen, it's not null, so we hide the `ListView`. Make sure to use `setState` in your `onTap` method. A simple demo would be

```
Column(
  children: [
    TextFormField(),
    if (selectedItem == null)
      ListView.builder(),
  ],
)
```